# Text to CSV with grepping fields based on a string as delimiter?

Tags: python, csv, text

I am trying to organize very long contact lists for import in MySQL database. Example looks like this:

```
John Doe                     
Manager
Some Company
B.A. in Sociology, Mary Washington College, M.Ed. in Human
Resources Development
COMMUNITY:
Library volunteer and reading tutor; Habitat for Humanity, Volunteer - Charity Works, Senior Women's Forum, Co-chair
KEY INTERESTS:
Transportation, Affordable housing.
```

Basically I need to split name, title, company, education, community and key interests out of this. Does anyone have an idea what would be good approach to this? I am thinking start line one as name, line 2 as title, line 3 as company, lines up to string "COMMUNITY" will be education, lines between "COMMUNITY" and "Key Interests" will be field community, and then the Key Interests field. The first 3 fields are on a single line, but the hard part is that some fields are multi-lines. If it would make the grepping easier, each field could possibly be made on a single line. Does anyone have an idea how/where to start? I have some minor scripting/programming skills but I'm certainly not a pro.

Appreciate any help!

P.S the end goal is to organize the data in a spreadsheet or similar format that can be imported into a database. Since there are "," inside the text, probably a different delimiter should be used, tab maybe?

P.S.2 The more I'm thinking about it, this can be simplified to `first_name last_name title organization bio`. It doesn't need to be so granular. I can put a blank line before the next contact, which can be a delimiter when the next contact starts.

P.S.3 So I was able to get what I need by Copy/Paste Special and Transpose in Excel.It turns each line in a separate field/column. Is there an easy way to automate this?

Comment: What would be your desired output for the input you've shown?

Comment: For importing the data, you have to insert a delimeter character in the output first. is that a "," or a ";" or something else you want.

Comment: It can be ";" and I'll make sure any existing ones are striped out from the text first. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I don't know much about Perl, I was looking into Python. I got it to work by cleaning my input text more and making each field into a separate line. Below is the format and the the program. Hope it helps someone.

```
Name
Job Title
Company
Education
COMMUNITY
Some text
KEY INTERESTS
Some text

import csv
from itertools import islice

# Open the text file
with open("contacts.txt", "r") as infile:

    # Create the output CSV file
    result_file = open("contacts_output.csv", 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')

    # Iterate trough the text file
    while True:

        # Split into chunks of 9 lines
        next_n_lines = list(islice(infile, 9))

        # Exit if there are no more lines
        if not next_n_lines:
            break

        # Process next_n_lines and write into the CSV file
        wr.writerow(next_n_lines)

# Close handles
infile.close()
result_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this dirty [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script. It uses `flip-flop` to check lines of text between `COMMUNITY` and `KEY INTERESTS`, and keeps them in an array to join with semicolon at the end. It surrounds them between double quotes because some lines already have semicolon in them, so it would be confusing:

```
perl -lne '
    $. < 4 && do { push @data, $_; next };
    if ( $flipflop = (($. == 4) .. (/^COMMUNITY:/)) ) {
        if ( $flipflop =~ /E0\z/ ) {
            push @data, $data; undef $data; $line = $.;
        } else {
            $data .= $_ . " ";
        }
        next;
    }
    if ( $flipflop = (($line + 1 == $.) .. (/^KEY\s+INTERESTS:/)) ) {
        if ( $flipflop =~ /E0\z/ ) {
            push @data, $data; undef $data;
        } else {
            $data .= $_ . " ";
        }
        next;
    }
    $data .= $_;
    push @data, $data if eof();
    printf qq|"%s"\n|, join q|";"|, @data;
' infile
```

It yields:

```
"John Doe";"Manager";"Some Company";"B.A. in Sociology, Mary Washington College, M.Ed. in Human Resources Development ";"Library volunteer and reading tutor; Habitat for Humanity, Volunteer - Charity Works, Senior Women's Forum, Co-chair ";"Transportation, Affordable housing."
```